# How do I add audio control in ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` controls volume using the following piece of code in its `output_packet` routine

```
// preprocess audio (volume)
if (ist->st->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
    if (audio_volume != 256) {
        short *volp;
        volp = samples;
        for(i=0;i<(decoded_data_size / sizeof(short));i++) {
            int v = ((*volp) * audio_volume + 128) >> 8;
            if (v < -32768) v = -32768;
            if (v >  32767) v = 32767;
            *volp++ = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something similar that can be done for `ffplay`?